# Rendering data from database

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, fetch-api

I am using react native to build an application. Using node js , express and mysql for the backend. 
Inserting data seems to work fine. But i am not able to retrieve data from the tables. This is the fetch API that i tried but i am not sure it is correct. I am new to React Native.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {
Text,
View
}from 'react-native';

export default class UserProfile extends Component{

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={name:''}
};

componentWillMount(){
    return this.getUser();
}

getUser(){
    return fetch('http://192.168.0.20:3000/users',{
    method:'GET',
    headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        }
    })
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((response) => this.setState({
    name: response.name})
    )
}


render(){
    return(
        <View style={{marginTop:100}}>
             <Text>UserName:{this.state.name}</Text>
        </View>

   );
 }
}
```

backend code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql =  require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',`enter code here`
      password: '',
      database:'backend',
})

/* our backend endpoint to check for users in the database */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

        var name=req.body.name;
        var phone=req.body.phone;
        var email = req.body.email;
        var password = req.body.password;

        connection.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email =? ",[email],function(err,row,fields){
          console.log(name);
          if (err) console.log(err);
  });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What does the `/userprofile` route look like in the Express app? Can you please provide that code?

Comment: After you get response , you are not saving the response to any variable.  Should not you set a part of responseData to this.state.name using setState ?

Comment: In your browser devtools console, are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @peteb i have added it.

Comment: @cjmling i did what you said. But still not getting any results. Please check the updated code.